# Definition of showing off

Tags: halal-haram, definitions

I know one is not allowed to show off with their religion (praying, fasting etc) but i have had this question in mind and couldn't find the answer i want so here it is:

Can one show off with, for example, house, maybe like their new room, or their car?

Answer (score 1):

Showing off it means that you try to look praiseworthy in the eyes of people, while one showing off with his worldly belongings leads him to be affected by the evil eye. I do not know if showing off  wealth is haram per se, but it is bad for the person themselves.